# How to create such a flow chart?

Tags: flow-charts

[image]

How can i create such a flow chart?
I will note come forward without your help.. so thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Yes, I did. But to be honest I am a beginner. I node that with the function \node [draw] at (0,0)  {Task} i can set the location of the node and then with the function \draw I can connect two nodes..
I have to put more effort in it, I know. But the flow charts which i found are not that what i am looking for..

Comment: With the irregular white shapes inside the frames?

Comment: haha bernard, no!  i feel ashamed xD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as starting point (exceptionally):

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=6mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning, shadows}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 5mm and 7mm,
   arr/.style = {-Triangle,very thick},
   box/.style = {rectangle, draw, semithick,
                 minimum height=9mm, minimum width=17mm,
                 fill=white, drop shadow},
                        ]
\node (n1) [box] {Task};
\node (n2) [box, below right=of n1] {Representation};
\node (n3) [box, above right=of n2] {Skils};
\node (n4) [box, below  left=of n2] {Difficulty};
\node (n5) [box, right=of n2] {Solution};
%
\draw[arr]   (n1) -| ([xshift=-3mm] n2.north);
\draw[arr]   (n3) -| ([xshift= 3mm] n2.north);
\draw[arr]   (n4) -| (n2);
\draw[arr]   (n2) -- (n5);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

fine tuning i left to you.

Comment: I don't know how i can express my gratitude to you. I already started reading in the latex book.. I will have a look how i can do the fine tuning. Thank Zarko!

Comment: see `tikz & pgf manual`, it is part of latext instalation. it is huge, but for start is sufficient read part III: Tikz ist kein zeichenprogram. if you will not receive better answer, you can accept mine :_-) (by clicking on check mark at the top left side of the answer).

Comment: Thank you for the hint! I will check out part three. I accepted now of course :)